# How to eject contact from active Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I have several contacts that need to be ejected from an active Journey. The contacts in question unsubscribed months ago but the send classification for the email activities is set to transactional. When attempting to edit the send classification on each email activity I'm presented with an error message stating the changes are unable to be made/published.

The only possible solution I can think of is accessing the send classification via the Admin menu, checking the 'Honor source and publication list level opt outs' box to prevent the contact from receiving further emails in the Journey.

Has anyone else tried this? Would this idea work to eject a contact from a Journey?

Comment: You could add an exclusion script to the existing email that is set up that will reference an unsubscribe data view or separate extension

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot make changes to the setup of an email activity that is part of an active journey. Otherwise you get the following error: Changes to the message were neither saved or published. I've confirmed this with SF support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some testing I found a workaround for what I'm trying to do. By utilizing the 'Auto-Suppression Configuration' setting in the admin menu I was able to create a suppression list that is applied to all mailings of a specific send classification or sender profile. Since we have a specific sender profile associated with the journey in question this allowed us to prevent the contact from receiving any future journey emails.

The 'Auto-Suppression Configuration' gets applied to all emails, including active journeys and active triggered sends that utilize the specified sender profile or send classification.

---

Edit for new functionality:
Per the [July 2020 Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_july2020_contact_path_in_JB.htm&type=5) individual contacts can be removed from an active journey via the Journey Health panel.

Contacts can also be removed via the [ContactExit API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/contactExitRequest.htm).

Comment: how do you deal with SMS, pushs ?

Comment: No idea, I'm not utilizing SMS for any journeys at the moment.